# ISO Fortran equivalent of AUTOMATIC and STATIC

Tags: fortran

Many Fortran compilers provide the `AUTOMATIC` and `STATIC` statements and attributes to explicitly define when a variable should be shared between invocations of a subroutine and when they should be allocated to the stack each time a subroutine is invoked.

Is there an equivalent in the ISO Fortran standards (any of them)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortran since FORTRAN 77 has the `SAVE` statement (and a `SAVE` attribute since Fortran 90) to share the variables between invocations. Automatic variables can be forced by declaring the procedure `recursive` (Fortran 90).

Comment: +1 - just wanted to add for the benefit of the OP that this is a very Fortran-y approach. Even mention of existence of a stack is too implementation-dependent for Fortran (a necessary approach for a language which has been used for 60 years), so you'll never see language features that specify heap vs stack.  On the other hand, constraints on what you want to accomplish - that a variable should be saved, or that a routine should be allowed to call itself - fit Fortran well.  It's one of the biggest if subtle conceptual differences between Fortran and the more bare-metal C-derived languages.

Comment: Thanks for the conceptual explanation.  What I have is some Fortran code written for the Intel compiler that I'm trying to get to also build with GFortran.  Several subroutines have large arrays as locals that may exceed the size at which they automatically become saved, so someone has declared them `AUTOMATIC`.  Is my best recourse here just to declare those subroutines `RECURSIVE`?